# Constructor of generic class having ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, constructor

Why doesn’t the constructor of my `Stock<E>` class work?

```
public class Stock<E>
{
    private ArrayList list;

    public Stock<E>()
    {
        this.list = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public void add(E item)
    {
        this.list.add(item);
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: Define, 'does not work' for you.

Comment: Can you please tell the issue?

Comment: Because the `list` private member is `ArrayList`, not `ArrayList<E>`.

Comment: @Palec Strictly, the code will still compile like that (but with warnings), the real problem is the `public Stock<E>() {...}`.

Comment: You should communicate with us and improve the question to include answers to the clarification requests. If any of the answers solved your problem (or helped you solve it yourself), you should mark it as accepted (click the checkmark), and you should upvote any useful answers. Only if you do this, the Q&A would be beneficial for future visitors, which is what [SO] is about.

Comment: Okay, we identified the issue. Now we can [edit] it into the question. I just made the basic cleanup, but don’t have a reasonably recent Java compiler here, so leaving the edit to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

The Generic Types are at wrong places

```
public class Stock<E> {
   private ArrayList<E> list;

   public Stock() {
      this.list= new ArrayList<E>();
   }

   public void add(E item) {
      this.list.add(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public Stock<E>()
    {
        this.list= new ArrayList<E>();
    }
```

to

```
public Stock()

{
    this.list = new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

and `private ArrayList list;` to `private ArrayList<E> list;`